# Настройка привелегий юзеров MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Изначально был создан пользователь `myuser` с правами как у суперюзера:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@%                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

У этого пользователя необходимо забрать доступ к БД `mysql`, но права на все остальные БД должны остаться прежними. Спустя пару часов попыток ничего не вышло.

Не подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте: `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* FROM 'myuser'@'%'`

Answer (score 1):

Можешь воспользоваться программой с графическим интерфейсом HeidiSQL или с помощью запроса

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* FROM 'newuser'@'localhost';

Забрать все права на БД у пользователя. Подробнее можно прочесть [тут](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mysql-ru)

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению. Есть вариант забрать сразу все права, а потом начать выдавать на нужные базы, но меня это не совсем устраивает. Возможно есть решение лучше